# ERR: No such file or directory, when using here doc on WSL2

Tags: bash, heredoc, wsl-2

```
$ cat <<EOF
abc
abc
abc
EOF
cat: -: No such file or directory
```

using here doc gives error on WSL2, am I missing some package that needs to be added or it is a WSL bug?

Comment: Can't reproduce. The wording of the error message suggests that you did not copy&paste the command verbatim. Could you make a screenshot and post the link in a comment? Also let us know what `cat --version` and `echo $BASH_VERSION` say.

Answer (score 1):

I too experienced the same issue. I discovered that I had set my `TMPDIR` environment variable to a path under `/mnt/c`. Once I unset the variable, it started working again.